Forwarding yubikey to Ubuntu Guest with Hyper-V causes Blue Screen
I am using Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04 in a Hyper-V guest.
Version information:
Microsoft Windows 11 Pro (x64)
10.0.22631 Build 22631

Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04
Kernel 6.5.0-44-generic

Hyper-V
Version 10.0.22621.3880

Hyper-V Manager
Version 10.0.22621.1

I am trying to use passkey authentication within a Hyper-V Linux Guest. I know someone who has a working setup so it must be possible. I more or less followed his instructions.
I installed usbipd-win (version 4.2.0). Then I more or less followed this guide (sorry it is in German, but the procedure should be clear anyway).
The yubikey is shared:

In the guest, I can see it too:

but whenever I try to attach it to the guest from within the guest with
sudo usbip attach --remote=<ip> --busid=2-3

the computer immediately freezes and soon after I get a blue screen.
I have set the RemoteFX USB Device Redirection in the host's GP as indicated here, the vhci module is loaded in the linux guest.
I don't know what else I can do! I checked the Windows Event Log but it doesn't contain anything conclusive, either. Any idea what I can do to analyze why the computer crashes is highly appreciated.
UPDATE
I added /usr/lib/linux-tools/6.5.0-44-generic to the secure_path in the sudoers file, after that the freezes and the bluescreen are gone. However, after running usbip attach on the Linux guest the Yubikey still doesn't show up when I type lsusb.
Here's the output of a call with debug output:
a@ky:~$ sudo usbip --debug attach -r 172.17.144.1 --busid=2-3 
usbip: debug: usbip.c:129:[run_command] running command: `attach'
usbip: debug: usbip_network.c:199:[usbip_net_recv_op_common] request failed at peer: 3
usbip: error: Attach Request for 2-3 failed - Device in error state

I switched off the Windows Defender Firewall but didn't help either.

Not a solution, but for privacy reasons you may want to blur out your windows shell prompt as well as it contains identifying information.

We will need logs from the VM and WinDBG analysis to help with the BSOD. If you are using the Yubikey to authenticate Windows you can't expect to be able to disconnect the device and attach it to the VM.

@Ramhound Bluescreen is gone, but connection to the host cannot be made for some reason, see updated post.

We need logs from Hyper-V to explain why the device goes into an error state. What generation of Hyper-V are we talking about?

@Ramhound Added Hyper-V version information to the post. 10.0.22621.3880. Is this what you were asking for?
